# JSTree's data.rslt.obj.text() returns an array of text rather than the text from the desired node

Tags: javascript, json, contextmenu, bind, jstree

I'm trying to have the jstree ONLY return the text for the node that I'm renaming.  Instead, it returns a concatenated list of the names of the current node as well as all of the child nodes.  I've configured the jstree to load on demand.  What can I do to limit the text returned by the contextmenu for renaming to only the node that I'm trying to rename?  Much appreciated!  Here is the full jstree code:

```
        $("#RequirementsTree")
    .bind("select_node.jstree", function(event, data) {
            if(is_requirement_node(data))
            {
                var id = data.rslt.obj.attr("id");

                if(id != null)
                {
                    $("#RequirementsTree").jstree('close_all')
                }
                else {
                    alert("Requirement node select error");
                }
            }
     })
    .bind("create.jstree", function(e, data) {
        // Ajax call to Server with parent node id and new node text
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Content("~/RMS/insertRequirementNode")',
            data: {
                    ParentID : ParentNode,
                    ChildNodeText : data.rslt.obj.text()
            },
            success: function(new_data) {
                $.jstree._reference($("#RequirementsTree")).refresh(-1);
                ParentNode = null;
                data = null;
                return new_data;
            }   
        });

        ParentNode = null;
        if (data.rslt.parent == -1) {
            alert("Can not create new root directory");
            // Rollback/delete the newly created node
            $.jstree.rollback(data.rlbk);
            return;
        }

        BranchReqFLag = null;
    }).bind("rename.jstree", function(e, data) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Content("~/RMS/updateRMSHierarchyNode")',
                data: {
                    NodeID: ParentNode,
                    NodeText: data.rslt.obj.text()
                },
                success: function() {
                    ParentNode = null;
                    data = null;
                }
            });
    }).jstree({
        json_data: {
            data: RBSTreeModel,
            ajax: {
                type: "POST",
                data: function (n) {
                    return {
                        NodeID: n.attr("id").substring(4),
                        Level: n.attr("name").substring(7)
                    };
                },
                url: function (node) {
                    return "/Audit/GetRequirementsTreeStructure";
                },
                success: function (new_data) {
                    return new_data;
                }
            }
        },
        contextmenu: {
            items: function($node) {
                    return {
                        createItem : {
                            "label" : "Create New Branch",
                            "action" : function(obj) { 
                                this.create(obj); 
                                BranchReqFlag = "Branch"; 
                                ParentNode = obj.attr("id").substring(4);
                            },
                            "separator_before" : true
                        },
                        renameItem : {
                            "label" : "Rename Branch",
                            "action" : function(obj) { 
                                this.rename(obj);
                                BranchReqFlag = "Branch";
                                ParentNode = obj.attr("id").substring(4);
                            },
                            "separator_before" : true
                        }
                    };
            }
        },
        plugins: ["themes", "json_data", "ui", "crrm", "contextmenu"]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data.rslt.new_name` holds the new name that was entered.  If you use Chrome or Firebugs to examine `data`, you will find the answer to most of these kinds of questions.

```
...
    }).bind("rename.jstree", function(e, data) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Content("~/RMS/updateRMSHierarchyNode")',
                data: {
                    NodeID: ParentNode,
                    NodeText: data.rslt.new_name
                },
                success: function() {
                    ParentNode = null;
                    data = null;
                }
            });
    })
...
```

Comment: OK, thanks!  And thanks for the advice on using Chrome/Firebug to examine the data more closely.